# Does the elemental monk's Water Whip require a source of water?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

The Way of the Four Elements monastic tradition includes the Water Whip discipline, which allows the monk to create a whip of water that shoves and pulls a creature to unbalance it. Does the monk require a source of water to form the whip? From a 'reality' perspective it would make sense.

The spell description doesn't say this is a spellcasting requirement, so the RAW answer is probably 'no', but I wanted to double check.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you don't need a source of water to create the whip.

Water Whip isn't a spell, therefore it doesn't follow the spellcasting rules of needing components found in chapter 10 of the PHB. Nor is there anything in its description that states such a requirement is needed.

Even if it were a spell, the section under the heading **Casting Elemental Spells** on page 80 states:

> To cast one of these spells, you use its casting time and other rules, but **you don’t need to provide material components for it.**

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't say anywhere that it requires a source of water, so it does not require a source of water

Comment: It also doesn't say that it has a somatic component, but it probably does... Maybe there are other implied components?

Comment: No, there are no implied components. As the accepted answer says, it is not even a spell. And if it was, there are NO implied components, all components are explicit.